# Laravel livewire editor not working when editing text. and ckeditor disappears

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I created a form using laravel livewire, but ckeditor disappears in the form. I did some research on the internet and used the wire:ignore command and it didn't show any benefit. I change the title in the form because of DOM Interaction, it does not change. I remove the Cke Editor script and it works. but not when cke editor is present. It disappears when you start typing. I will be glad if you can help me with my problem.

Script File

```
     <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#description'))
            .then(editor => {
                editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                    @this.set('description', editor.getData());
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>
```

Html File

```
      <div class="mb-3" wire:ignore>
          <label for="setting-input-2" class="form-label">Description</label>:
         <textarea wire:model.defer="description" class="form-control" id="description" 
             name="description">{!! $description !!}
                                    
       </textarea>

              </div>
```

Comment: I am having same issue here. Any progress on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This code block seems to be ok, but you need to use wire ignore for the outer div of the text-area field.

The CKEditor begins changing the DOM as soon as they are initialized, and it keeps doing so as you interact with them. Since Livewire won't be able to keep track of this, we can use the wire:ignore tag in this circumstance. It informs Livewire to ignore this portion of the DOM. The code's subsequent section has achieved the following:

```
......
<div wire:ignore>
    <textarea wire:model="message"
              class="min-h-fit h-48 "
              name="message"
              id="message"></textarea>
</div>
......
```

In here I think you haven't use wire:ignore.self outer of the form element.

I found this article regarding your issue [How to use CKEditor in Livewire Laravel 10](https://techielash.me/how-to-use-ckeditor-in-livewire-laravel-10-step-by-step-guide/)